# Convert if else statement in Optional.ofNullable().ifPresent() in Java

Tags: java, spring, option-type

I have this statement in java

```
if (payload.get("mimeType") != null) {
    lettersPayload.put("mimeType", payload.get("mimeType"));

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(heytype) && !"all".equals(type)) {
        lettersPayload.put("heytype", heytype);
    }
}
```

I have a requirment to do this code snippet with `Optional.ofNullable().ifPresent()`
I wrote these:

```
Optional.of(payload.get("mimeType")).ifPresent(name -> lettersPayload.put("heytype", heytype));
```

The second statement is crushing

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: "is crushing" ... isPresent doesn't take parameters afaik.

Comment: If `requestPayload.get(MIME_TYPE)` may be null, you should use `Optional.ofNullable`.

Comment: are you trying to solve nested `if`s using `Optional`? rather than using `ifPresent` to perform an operation, make use if `isPresent` to check and perrforrm both the operation, even if that is so.. Something like `Optional<String> opt =   Optional.ofNullable(payload.get("mimeType"));
        opt.ifPresent(p -> lettersPayload.put("mimeType", p));
        if(opt.isPresent() && !StringUtils.isEmpty(heytype) && !"all".equals(type)) {
            lettersPayload.put("heytype", heytype);
        }` which reads worse than your current code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) if you are not sure whether the value you want to wrap as Optional is null or not.

Your code can then be rewritten:

```
Optional.ofNullable(payload.get("mimeType")).ifPresent(mimeType -> {...})
```